# how do i prevent an image from being bigger than the parent tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I want to have the logo as the home button, i have the image as a link on the nav bar, but its very tiny, i want it to fill the height of the nav bar. In css i gave the height as 50 px to the nav class. Is there a way to make any items placed in a container to not be bigger than the boundaries of the container ?

[image]

```
import Link from "next/link"; import navStyles from "../styles/Nav.module.css"; import Image from "next/image";

const Nav = () => {   return (
    <nav className={navStyles.nav}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link href="/">
            <a className={navStyles.a}>
              <Image
                className={navStyles.logo}
                width="40.3px"
                height="21.3px"
                src="/blue.png"
              />
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>   ); }; export default Nav;


.nav {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  
  .nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .nav ul li a {
    margin: 5px 15px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }
  .logo{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

When I set the image height and width to 100%, the image is bigger than the nav bar,
[image]

How do I restrict the image to the height of its parent div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: block` and `max-height: 100%` to the image element:

```
.logo{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap Image tag with div and make width and height 100% !important